# Como ocultar meu RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Eu tenho um evento no meu *adapter* que controla o *click* nos itens da *recyclerview*. Gostaria de saber qual código devo adicionar que ao clicar no item, a *recycler view* seja ocultada

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.titulo.setText(nomeList.get(position));
        holder.autor.setText(user_cadastroList.get(position));
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

CadastrarAplicacao.getUsuario().setText(nomeList.get(position).toString());

//Depois disso queria ocultar a RecyclerView

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você terá que passar o evento de clique por parâmetro da `Activity` para o `Adapter`. no seu Adapter adicione essa interface:

```
public interface OnItemClickLister {
    void onItemClick(String nome);
}
```

Na sua Activity chame o Adapter dessa forma:

```
SeuAdapter adapter = new SeuAdapter(itens, new SeuAdapter.OnItemClickLister() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String nome) {
             CadastrarAplicacao.getUsuario().setText(nomeList.get(position).toString());

             suaRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

E finalmente no seu evento de clique do Adapter, adicione:

```
holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(nomeList.get(position).toString());
}});
```